# li tag should display none from multiple li listing tag

Tags: html, css

Following is my listing:-

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-heading">Menu</div>
  <div class="box-content">
    <ul>
            <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Edit Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Password</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Admin</a></li> <!--display none-->
            <li><a href="#">Address Books</a></li><!--display none-->
            <li><a href="#">Emails &amp; Notifications</a></li><!--display none-->
            <li><a href="#">Order Now</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Order History</a></li><!--display none-->
            <li><a href="#">Pending Orders</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Current Orders</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Completed Orders</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>//display none
            <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>//display none
            <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I dont want to display the following list they are:-

Contact Admin

- Address Books
- Emails & Notifications
- Order History
- Downloads
- Newsletter

using css how can i display the above list as none

THanks in advance.

Comment: can't you give any class to those li ?

Comment: you can add position in css - 
ul li:nth-child(4) {
  display: none;
}

Comment: hello @TBI can i use id of div with ul li?

Comment: yes, you can use id/class of div. In your example use

.box-content ul li:nth-child(4) { display:none; }

Answer (score 2):

The most flexible solution is to add a class to the list items you want to hide, e.g.:

```
<li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Edit Account</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Password</a></li>
<li class="foo"><a href="#">Contact Admin</a></li> <!--display none-->
<li class="foo"><a href="#">Address Books</a></li><!--display none-->
<li class="foo"><a href="#">Emails &amp; Notifications</a></li><!--display none-->
<li><a href="#">Order Now</a></li>
<li class="foo"><a href="#">Order History</a></li><!--display none-->
<li><a href="#">Pending Orders</a></li>
```

Then

```
.foo {
    display: none;
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/mimesemi/2)

But if you can't do that, you pretty much have no choice but to use [`:nth-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) (counting starts with 1, unlike most programming stuff):

```
ul li:nth-child(4),
ul li:nth-child(5),
ul li:nth-child(6),
ul li:nth-child(8) {
    display: none;
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/mimesemi/3)

That would, of course, hide those list items in *every* list, so you'll want to lock that down a bit more specifically.

The problem with doing it this way is, of course, that if you modify the list later, you have to change those indexes. It's fragile. Using a class is more robust.

Comment: Isn't this just a combination of the previous two answers?

Comment: @JamesHunt: I don't know, there weren't any answers when I started writing. *Edit*: Looks like it, but as this is more complete, I'll leave it.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.hidden
{
    display:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li class="hidden"><a href="#">Contact Admin</a></li> <!--display none-->
<li class="hidden"><a href="#">Address Books</a></li><!--display none-->
<li class="hidden"><a href="#">Emails &amp; Notifications</a></li><!--display none-->
<li><a href="#">Order Now</a></li>
<li class="hidden"><a href="#">Order History</a></li><!--display none-->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use in-line css you should add a style to your `ul` element:

```
<li style="display:none;">
```

otherwise you use a class and setting the property display:none;

```
<style>
.hide{
  display:none;
}
</style>

<li class="hide">
```